# How to make protractor run with puppeteer and chrome 78?

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver, puppeteer, angular-e2e

I am using Protractor for Angular E2E Tests + Puppeteer for a consistent Chrome Version in all CI-Servers.

Lately I am getting `SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 78` Errors.

Although the installed versions of puppeteer (1.20.0 -> [Chromium 78.0.3882.0](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md)) and webdriver-manager are matching.

Any ideas on how to solve this?
For more information from the build you can see the CI log [here](https://dev.azure.com/T-Systems-MMS/phonebook/_build/results?buildId=1784&view=logs&j=10f66467-59e5-53bc-0c8a-42cc89770de4) and the project [here](https://github.com/T-Systems-MMS/phonebook/blob/master/Phonebook.Frontend/package.json)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem to this, however my issue was with Chrome 81.

`E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81`

My solution was the below two steps:

1) Dont let Angular install the latest available webdriver for you when running `ng e2e`, by using the `--webdriverUpdate` flag and setting it to `false`.

2) Use the `webdriver-manager` from protractor and manually specify which webdriver to use:

`node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=80.0.3987.106 --gecko false --standalone false`

3) add this to the "pree2e" step as to be automatically executed before the e2e step:

`"pree2e": "node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=80.0.3987.106 --gecko false --standalone false"`

To see which webdrivers are installed, use `node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager status`.

https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/blob/legacy/docs/versions.md#download-a-specific-version

https://angular.io/cli/e2e#options

versions used:

```
"protractor": "5.4.3"
"puppeteer": "2.1.1"

Angular CLI: 9.1.0
Node: 12.2.0
OS: linux x64
```

Answer (score 2):

This has been an issue for a few months now. There are several threads on their github repo around it. The workaround for me has been to navigate to `~/node_modules/protractor` and manually install `webdriver-manager@latest`. You should see webdriver-manager@12.1.7 installed.

```
> cd node_modules\protractor
> npm i webdriver-manager@latest
```

Comment: Hello @tehbeardedone, could you post links to the issues/threads you mentioned?

Comment: These are the first ones I came across when this first happened to me. https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5312 and https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/420. There are plenty of other similar issues posted on their github repo.